# Can I run different commands in different replicas of the same deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a deployment in Kubernetes with a ConfigMap, including a set of configuration commands as a script. It works as expected when there's only 1 replica.

Is there a way where I can create a second pod that executes a different set of commands from the first pod?

For example when the first pod is being created, it will execute `script-1.sh`. But I want to execute a different script (maybe like `script-2.sh`) in the second pod and so on. Only for the first time pod I need to execute `script-1.sh`. For the next pods which are created, it should execute `script-2.sh` not `script-1.sh`.

Is there a way I can do this?

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - name: config-script
    mountPath: /scripts
volumes:
  - name: config-script
    configMap:
      name: config-script-1
      defaultMode: 0744
```

Comment: I do agree with the answer provided by Krishna Chaurasia. You can't do it by itself. What you can do as a **workaround** is to use `Helm` and template your `Deployments` (with single replica) to have different `Configmaps` mounted that would be used.

Comment: Then can I use custom configMaps? For example, to run a set of commands in the primary (Or the first pod) and and different set of commands in the replicated pods. I'm having only 1 replica.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: sorry for that it was a mistake. sorry guys

Comment: @yatin sorry mistake

Comment: I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this with `Deployments`. A Deployment runs identical replicas of your application and you can't have different pods of same `Deployment` run different scripts.

Comment: Then can I use custom configMaps? For example, to run a set of commands in the primary (Or the first pod) and and different set of commands in the replicated pods. I'm having only 1 replica.

Comment: No, there is no notion of primary/secondary with Deploymens. Have a look at statefulsets if you want to act based on the state of the pod.

Comment: If I create a statefulset instead of a deployments, can I fulfill my requirement?

Comment: I can't comment on that since I don't know the full requirements. I can just say that statefulsets have a notion of state and they are generally used for the master/slave architecture. I would suggest to read the docs and see if you can map your requirements to the statefulsets behaviour.

Comment: You can also run two Deployments, with the same `image:` but different `command:`.

Comment: With a StatefulSet, the "primary" will have a **hostname**(1) ending in `...-0` and you can test on that.  But this isn't an active/passive failover situation; the first pod will always be "primary" and the later ones will always be "secondary".

Answer (score 2):

Without the specification on what exactly your scripts are doing, it could be hard to point you to the most viable and correct solution.

As stated previously in my comment, I do agree with answer provided by Krishna Chaurasia. It's not intended use to run a `Deployment` when each of the replicas has some differences from one another.

By not taking into consideration:

- What exactly this scripts are doing.
- The amount of replicas in each `Deployment`.
- If/how they are connected to each other.
- etc.

You can create a Helm chart that would iterate over certain values and produce either:

- `X` amount of `Pods` that are running with their desired scripts.
- `X` amounts of `Deployments`/`StatefulSets` (**with single `replica`** each) that are running with their desired scripts.

---

#### **Please do consider this as a workaround of how it can be done, not acknowledging the use case!**

With following setup of a `Helm` Chart:

```sh
test-directory: 
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   └── deployment.yaml
└── values.yaml

1 directory, 4 files
```

Where the contents of the following files are:

- `Chart.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: ubuntu-scripts
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
version: 0.1.0
```

- `values.yaml`

```yaml
scripts: 
  - script-one # see the configmap, what it does
  - script-two # see the configmap, what it does
```

- `configmap.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: scripts-configmap
data:
  script-one: |
    echo "Hello there!" 
  script-two: |
    echo "General Kenobi!"
```

- `deployment.yaml`

```yaml
{{- range .Values.scripts }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-{{ . }}
  labels:
    app: ubuntu-{{ . }} 
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu 
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: 
    - sleep 
    - infinity
    volumeMounts:
    - name: placeholder
      mountPath: /scripts
  volumes:
  - name: placeholder
    configMap:
      name: scripts-configmap
      items:
      - key: {{ . }}
        path: script.sh 
      defaultMode: 0744
---
{{- end }}
```

After applying above resources with:

- `helm install NAME .`  ( being in the `Helm` Chart directory)

> A side note!
>
> `Helm` will iterate over the `Values.scripts` (included in `values.yaml`) running a loop for each of the items in it. It will also parse the value that is been iterating over in place of `{{ . }}`.
>
> You can see how it will behave by running:
>
> - `helm install ubuntu . --dry-run --debug`

You will see:

```sh
NAME                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ubuntu-script-one   1/1     Running   0          4m12s
ubuntu-script-two   1/1     Running   0          4m12s
```

And checking the mounted scripts:

- `kubectl exec -it ubuntu-script-one -- sh /scripts/script.sh`

```sh
Hello there!
```

- `kubectl exec -it ubuntu-script-two -- sh /scripts/script.sh`

```sh
General Kenobi!
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> You can also substitute the `Pod` for `Deployment`/`StatefulSet` (adding additional fields) but only with: `replicas: 1`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)*
- *[Helm.sh](https://helm.sh/)*